# C# app doesn't use proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, html-agility-pack

I've made an app which is using HtmlAgilityPack to GET and POST data by Requests. Unfortunelly I have to have different ip every single POST. What I did is downloaded `proxy changer` programs like:

https://github.com/shubhsblog/Auto-proxy-changer

https://github.com/mwiedemeyer/ProxySwitcher

http://www.eliteproxyswitcher.com/

Basically the programs are changing this tab:

[image]

What has to be said, when i use proxy changer andI go manually to the webpage (the same webpage used to send GET and POST in my c# app) my ip is changed, so it seems to work.

Unfortunelly not. My ip (proxy) is changed only in browser. When my c# app trying to POST data it is visible as my default ip. I dont understand why my ip is changed only in browser. My c# app seems to have unchanged ip. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: As you show no code, chances are your web requests are done from your app not through a browser, ergo its not using the settings in the browser but just raw from your pc

Comment: I think I dont have to show you my code, because code does not contain any proxy change method. The only way I change proxy is by external software.

Comment: Exactly, so your app isnt using it.